# Please, how do I make this HTML code responsive

Tags: html

Please help... How do I make this HTML code responsive? It is an HTML code for collecting emails. It does quite well in desktop view but only shows half of it on mobile.

**PS: I do not qualify even as an HTML newbie.**

```
<div class="box" style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-size: medium; max-width: 640px; min-width: 200px; width: 640px; text-align: center; margin: auto; border-radius: 8px; padding-bottom: 16px; box-shadow: black 0px 8px 6px -6px; border: 10px solid #428bca;">
<p><strong style="font-family: Georgia;"><span style="color: #cc0000; font-size: xx-large;"><span style="background-color: #ffff00; color: #000000;"><img alt="" height="351" src="http://awealthywallet.com/SEF-pop-up.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" width="606" /></span></span></strong></p>

<div style="width: 100%; max-width: 820px; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color: white; text-align: center; margin: 1% auto 0; -webkit-border-radius: 8px; -moz-border-radius: 8px; border-radius: 8px; padding-bottom: 34px !important; padding-top: 1px !important; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px white; box-shadow: 0px 8px 6px -6px white;">
<div><button onclick="document.getElementById('openModal').style.display='block';" style="width: 88%; margin-top: 0px; background-color: #f00; border: 2px solid #f00; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 30px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) inset; box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) inset; padding: 10px; color: white; white-space: normal;" type="button">GET INSTANT DOWNLOAD!</button></div>
</div>

<p><span style="font-family: tahoma, geneva, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 18px;"><!-- Main Box Ends --><!-- Light Box Starts --></span></span></p>

<div id="openModal" style="display: none; position: fixed; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: center; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); z-index: 99999; overflow: auto;">
<div style="width: 75%; max-width: 450px; position: relative; margin: 10% auto 0; padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px; background-color: #ffffff;"><a href="#close" id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('openModal').style.display='none';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('close').style.background='#606061';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('close').style.background='#00d9ff';" style="background: #606061; color: #fff; line-height: 25px; position: absolute; right: -12px; text-align: center; top: -10px; width: 24px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; -webkit-border-radius: 12px; -moz-border-radius: 12px; border-radius: 12px; -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;" title="Close">X</a>

<h2>Enter Your Name &amp; Best Email To Download!</h2>

<div>
<form action="http://www.aiop-response.com/subscribe.php" method="post"><input align="middle" name="name" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Name';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') {this.value = '';}" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #dfdfdf; height: 41px; width: 75%; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial; color: #666; background-color: white;" type="text" value="Enter Your Name" /> <input align="middle" name="email" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Primary Email';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Primary Email') {this.value = '';}" style="-webkit-border-radius: 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; border: 2px solid #dfdfdf; height: 41px; width: 75%; margin-top: 10px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px; font-family: Arial; color: #666; background-color: white;" type="text" value="Enter Your Primary Email" /> <input style="position: relative; width: 75%; margin-top: 10px; background-color: #f00; border: 2px solid #f00; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; cursor: pointer; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) inset; box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) inset; padding: 10px; color: black; white-space: normal;" type="Submit" value="YES, SENT IT NOW" /> <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="111377" /></form>

<div style="font-size: 16px; padding: 10px;">We Respect Your Privacy</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to use css media queries two links https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp and https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp ... just go through them and everything should work fine.

Comment: your current inline styling wont work good for responsive design in fact it will fall apart left and right unless you use css classes which would switch styling according to media hence the above two links for css media queries.

Comment: @Syed, I think I forgot to add that I do not even qualify as a newbie. I looked through the links and I quite understand them but for someone without no background knowledge on CSS or HTML, I don't know what to do. I understand it is a lot to ask, but could you help return a proper result using CSS media queries, please?

Comment: I could would take time and secondly since it would be away from above question you might as well open up new question thread. Secondly if you feel you understand whats going on in those  links then please have a look this media query based css library and will get you going ..... https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/defaulT.asp

Comment: Thanks though. I guess I would have to close this.